# social_auth_app_django pipeline: first time visitor issue

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I'm trying to implement social auth with google-oauth2. I almost implemented it, but I'm confused about first-time social visitor scenario:

- Suppose the social user visited my site for the first time and attempted to authenticate with Google. In this case he won't be logged in, but only registered on my website.
- In order to log in this user has to click on Google authentication button the second time, and now, when he has already registered on my system the logging in will be successful.

Questions:

Is it a standard routine for the first time visitors?

Is it possible to log the social user on the first attempt?

I'm using the following social auth pipeline:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    # Get the information we can about the user and return it in a simple
    # format to create the user instance later. In some cases the details are
    # already part of the auth response from the provider, but sometimes this
    # could hit a provider API.
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',

    # Get the social uid from whichever service we're authing thru. The uid is
    # the unique identifier of the given user in the provider.
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',

    # Verifies that the current auth process is valid within the current
    # project, this is where emails and domains whitelists are applied (if
    # defined).
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',

    # Checks if the current social-account is already associated in the site.
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',

    # Associates the current social details with another user account with
    # a similar email address. Disabled by default.
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',

    # Send a validation email to the user to verify its email address.
    # Disabled by default.
    # 'social_core.pipeline.mail.mail_validation',

    # Make up a username for this person, appends a random string at the end if
    # there's any collision.
    'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',

    # Create a user account if we haven't found one yet.
    'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',

    # Create the record that associates the social account with the user.
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',

    # Populate the extra_data field in the social record with the values
    # specified by settings (and the default ones like access_token, etc).
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',

    # Update the user record with any changed info from the auth service.
    'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```

Thank you in advance for advises, answers, and comments!

Comment: Python-social-auth will log your user in automatically, they should be logged in after the register flow. Do you have any other configuration that could affect this flow? Are your users marked as `is_active`?

Comment: Hi omab! Super glad to get you there! :) If the user is registered within the application, then everything goes well, and authorization works as expected. My question is about unregistered user, it seems that by default, if I click Google Authentication button, the user gets registered, but he doesn't get logged in. In order to log in he needs to click Google Authentication button again. :)

Comment: I expect, that I have an issue with the workflow. Probably, the correct way would be to separate the registration and the logging in processeses.

Comment: That's the thing, the process is the same, only difference is that a user is creates if there's none in the current aession

Comment: We need to identify what's blocking that login on register, somehow the session might not be getting stored properly, do you have anything else configured related to this?

Comment: 1) I'm using a custom user model. I will check my code using Django user model. 2) My user registration procedure does not logging the user in as well (this was done intentionally), the user is redirected to logging in view, and has to input his credentials. However, I do not think, that social_auth_django_app knows this.

Comment: Is newly created user session, created at stage 'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user'?